# Facing issue while installing 2 different Xamarin Application in mobile device

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I had developed 2 different Xamarin Applications, the first application was installed easily but when I install the second one in the same device it shows me the message.

> "Do you want to install an update to this existing application? Your
>   existing data will not be lost. It does not require any special
>   access."

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Both apps are using the same package identifier.

Comment: Thanks, David for your reply,
But I am new in xamarin. can you please guide me for that?
I don't know what to do?

Comment: Change one of them!

Comment: How ? can you tell me steps ?

Comment: Maybe you could Google it? This kind of thing is something you should have learned very early on, seems like you've skipped ahead in whatever learning you were doing.

Comment: Ohk Great, I got it. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You probably have the same package name for both applications. If you are using Visual Studio go to your project properties and change the package name:

[image]